# LaTex macro to make LaTex more human-friendly in Math?

Tags: math, latex, macros

How can I make a LaTex macro which replaces each

1. \and by the word "and"
2. \or by the word "or"

so that the nouns are not in italics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\text{and}` or `\text{or}`

If you insist on a macro, just use the normal LaTeX `\newcommand.`

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can make an alias of \and so that it applies to \text{and}?

Comment: You need to load the amsmath package (or amstext, at a minimum) for this to work.

Comment: No you don't.  \text is plain LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

In math mode `\mbox{}` gives the argument upright (roman) typesetting.

Comment: The advantage to \text is that the font size adjusts in different situations (such as subscripts/superscripts). Although that's not always important...